# Using bootstrap-daterangepicker in an Angular directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm having troubles using bootstrap-daterangepicker in an Angular directive. It works fine when initially loading the page, but when switching pages/states (I'm using ui-router) and going back to a page with a daterangepicker the plugin doesn't work anymore.

It throws this error:

> TypeError: $(...).daterangepicker is not a function

It seems like the plugin has removed itself when changing states. Anyone an idea how to fix this?

```
app.directive("daterangepicker", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      scope: false,
      link: function($scope, $element, $attr){

        $($element).daterangepicker({
          format: "DD.MM.YYYY",
          startDate: moment().subtract('days', 1),
          endDate: new Date(),          
          buttonClasses: ['btn-primary'],
        }, function(from, to) {
          $scope.date = {from: from, to: to};
          $scope.$apply(); // I need apply() here to use the two-way-databinding
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: No no no... Use https://github.com/fragaria/angular-daterangepicker not the jQuery version

Comment: Yeah, I also tried that one, it relies on the jQuery version as a dependency and has the same issue like I have.

Comment: No wonder why you get this error, if this is how you're using the angularjs version

Comment: The docs literally state that you should include boostrap-daterangepicker as a dependency https://github.com/fragaria/angular-daterangepicker

Comment: Yes, of course, but your integration is wrong. Take a look on how they implement it AngularJS style (Example: `<input date-range-picker class="form-control date-picker" type="text" ng-model="date" min="'2014-02-23'" max="'2015-02-25'"/>`). I'm using this module and it work like charm. You just need to ditch the jQuery integration style - You also have a working example of this http://fragaria.github.io/angular-daterangepicker/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the solution to my problem!

To be clear: the same bug was happening with the angular-daterangepicker plugin.

It was actually caused because some other dependency loaded an extra jQuery. Because of this multiple jQuerys were loaded and this caused the bug.

Answer (score 5):

I would avoid reinventing the wheel, there is already a directive provided by several projects, use the https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Import the module:

> angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);

and the use it like that:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.2.js"></script>
  <script src="example.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <style>
    .full button span {
      background-color: limegreen;
      border-radius: 32px;
      color: black;
    }

    .partially button span {
      background-color: orange;
      border-radius: 32px;
      color: black;
    }
  </style>
  <div ng-controller="DatepickerPopupDemoCtrl">
    <pre>Selected date is: <em>{{dt | date:'fullDate' }}</em></pre>

    <h4>Popup</h4>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>

          </span>
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="dt" is-open="popup2.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open2()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>

          </span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Format: <span class="muted-text">(manual alternate <em>{{altInputFormats[0]}}</em>)</span></label>
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="format" ng-options="f for f in formats">
          <option></option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <hr />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" ng-click="today()">Today</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" ng-click="setDate(2009, 7, 24)">2009-08-24</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ng-click="clear()">Clear</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" ng-click="toggleMin()" uib-tooltip="After today restriction">Min date</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The controller:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('DatepickerPopupDemoCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.today = function() {
        $scope.dt = new Date();
      };
      $scope.today();

      $scope.clear = function() {
        $scope.dt = null;
      };

      $scope.inlineOptions = {
        customClass: getDayClass,
        minDate: new Date(),
        showWeeks: true
      };

      $scope.dateOptions = {
        dateDisabled: disabled,
        formatYear: 'yy',
        maxDate: new Date(2020, 5, 22),
        minDate: new Date(),
        startingDay: 1
      };

      // Disable weekend selection
      function disabled(data) {
        var date = data.date,
          mode = data.mode;
        return mode === 'day' && (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);
      }

      $scope.toggleMin = function() {
        $scope.inlineOptions.minDate = $scope.inlineOptions.minDate ? null : new Date();
        $scope.dateOptions.minDate = $scope.inlineOptions.minDate;
      };

      $scope.toggleMin();

      $scope.open1 = function() {
        $scope.popup1.opened = true;
      };

      $scope.open2 = function() {
        $scope.popup2.opened = true;
      };

      $scope.setDate = function(year, month, day) {
        $scope.dt = new Date(year, month, day);
      };

      $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
      $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
      $scope.altInputFormats = ['M!/d!/yyyy'];

      $scope.popup1 = {
        opened: false
      };

      $scope.popup2 = {
        opened: false
      };

      var tomorrow = new Date();
      tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
      var afterTomorrow = new Date();
      afterTomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
      $scope.events = [{
        date: tomorrow,
        status: 'full'
      }, {
        date: afterTomorrow,
        status: 'partially'
      }];

      function getDayClass(data) {
        var date = data.date,
          mode = data.mode;
        if (mode === 'day') {
          var dayToCheck = new Date(date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

          for (var i = 0; i < $scope.events.length; i++) {
            var currentDay = new Date($scope.events[i].date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

            if (dayToCheck === currentDay) {
              return $scope.events[i].status;
            }
          }
        }

        return '';
      }
    });
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/LZgUAZQkNKgDrUZAVWSa?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this before initializing the `daterangepicker` in the `directive`.

```
if (!jQuery().daterangepicker) {
     return;
}

$($element).daterangepicker({...});
```

Comment: This prevents the error from triggering but it does not initialise the picker anymore...

Comment: Can you verify the order in which the JS files are defined in your master html are right ?